# ¿Obtener duracion de mp3 en php?

Tags: php

Quiero obtener la duracion de un mp3 y estoy usando http://www.zedwood.com/article/php-calculate-duration-of-mp3 pero no me funciona. No sé qué estoy haciendo mal. ¿Tengo que importar algo?

```
<?php

  $mp3file = new MP3File("audio.mp3");

  $duracion = $mp3file->getDuration();

  echo $duracion;

 ?>
```

Comment: No entiendo. ¿Qué sería la duración, pero no en segundos? ¿Qué duración es la que estás intentando obtener? ¿Cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: Quiero obtener la duración en segundos, pero no me funciona no se que estoy haciendo mal, tengo que importar algo?

Comment: ¿ Solo estas haciendo lo que muestras, sin copiar los archivos de definición de las clases a tu equipo, ni importarlos, ni nada ? ¿ solo el código que muestras ?

Comment: si, solo tengo el mp3file.class.php en el mismo directorio.

Comment: @Hamwen ¿estás usando la clase que está en el enlace que publicaste? ¿Cómo estás usando esa clase? ¿En qué parte de tu código?

Comment: El código que he compartido es todo el código que tengo en un .php, después tengo otro fichero mp3file.class.php en el mismo directorio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta hacer lo siguiente:

**Pasos**

1. Crea una carpeta en la raíz de tu servidor, por ejemplo, `mp3file`.
2. En dicho directorio, crea el archivo `mp3file.class.php` copia y pega en el mismo, este código:

```html
<?php
class MP3File
{
    protected $filename;
    public function __construct($filename)
    {
        $this->filename = $filename;
    }
 
    public static function formatTime($duration) //as hh:mm:ss
    {
        //return sprintf("%d:%02d", $duration/60, $duration%60);
        $hours = floor($duration / 3600);
        $minutes = floor( ($duration - ($hours * 3600)) / 60);
        $seconds = $duration - ($hours * 3600) - ($minutes * 60);
        return sprintf("%02d:%02d:%02d", $hours, $minutes, $seconds);
    }
 
    //Read first mp3 frame only...  use for CBR constant bit rate MP3s
    public function getDurationEstimate()
    {
        return $this->getDuration($use_cbr_estimate=true);
    }
 
    //Read entire file, frame by frame... ie: Variable Bit Rate (VBR)
    public function getDuration($use_cbr_estimate=false)
    {
        $fd = fopen($this->filename, "rb");
 
        $duration=0;
        $block = fread($fd, 100);
        $offset = $this->skipID3v2Tag($block);
        fseek($fd, $offset, SEEK_SET);
        while (!feof($fd))
        {
            $block = fread($fd, 10);
            if (strlen($block)<10) { break; }
            //looking for 1111 1111 111 (frame synchronization bits)
            else if ($block[0]=="\xff" && (ord($block[1])&0xe0) )
            {
                $info = self::parseFrameHeader(substr($block, 0, 4));
                if (empty($info['Framesize'])) { return $duration; } //some corrupt mp3 files
                fseek($fd, $info['Framesize']-10, SEEK_CUR);
                $duration += ( $info['Samples'] / $info['Sampling Rate'] );
            }
            else if (substr($block, 0, 3)=='TAG')
            {
                fseek($fd, 128-10, SEEK_CUR);//skip over id3v1 tag size
            }
            else
            {
                fseek($fd, -9, SEEK_CUR);
            }
            if ($use_cbr_estimate && !empty($info))
            { 
                return $this->estimateDuration($info['Bitrate'],$offset); 
            }
        }
        return round($duration);
    }
 
    private function estimateDuration($bitrate,$offset)
    {
        $kbps = ($bitrate*1000)/8;
        $datasize = filesize($this->filename) - $offset;
        return round($datasize / $kbps);
    }
 
    private function skipID3v2Tag(&$block)
    {
        if (substr($block, 0,3)=="ID3")
        {
            $id3v2_major_version = ord($block[3]);
            $id3v2_minor_version = ord($block[4]);
            $id3v2_flags = ord($block[5]);
            $flag_unsynchronisation  = $id3v2_flags & 0x80 ? 1 : 0;
            $flag_extended_header    = $id3v2_flags & 0x40 ? 1 : 0;
            $flag_experimental_ind   = $id3v2_flags & 0x20 ? 1 : 0;
            $flag_footer_present     = $id3v2_flags & 0x10 ? 1 : 0;
            $z0 = ord($block[6]);
            $z1 = ord($block[7]);
            $z2 = ord($block[8]);
            $z3 = ord($block[9]);
            if ( (($z0&0x80)==0) && (($z1&0x80)==0) && (($z2&0x80)==0) && (($z3&0x80)==0) )
            {
                $header_size = 10;
                $tag_size = (($z0&0x7f) * 2097152) + (($z1&0x7f) * 16384) + (($z2&0x7f) * 128) + ($z3&0x7f);
                $footer_size = $flag_footer_present ? 10 : 0;
                return $header_size + $tag_size + $footer_size;//bytes to skip
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
 
    public static function parseFrameHeader($fourbytes)
    {
        static $versions = array(
            0x0=>'2.5',0x1=>'x',0x2=>'2',0x3=>'1', // x=>'reserved'
        );
        static $layers = array(
            0x0=>'x',0x1=>'3',0x2=>'2',0x3=>'1', // x=>'reserved'
        );
        static $bitrates = array(
            'V1L1'=>array(0,32,64,96,128,160,192,224,256,288,320,352,384,416,448),
            'V1L2'=>array(0,32,48,56, 64, 80, 96,112,128,160,192,224,256,320,384),
            'V1L3'=>array(0,32,40,48, 56, 64, 80, 96,112,128,160,192,224,256,320),
            'V2L1'=>array(0,32,48,56, 64, 80, 96,112,128,144,160,176,192,224,256),
            'V2L2'=>array(0, 8,16,24, 32, 40, 48, 56, 64, 80, 96,112,128,144,160),
            'V2L3'=>array(0, 8,16,24, 32, 40, 48, 56, 64, 80, 96,112,128,144,160),
        );
        static $sample_rates = array(
            '1'   => array(44100,48000,32000),
            '2'   => array(22050,24000,16000),
            '2.5' => array(11025,12000, 8000),
        );
        static $samples = array(
            1 => array( 1 => 384, 2 =>1152, 3 =>1152, ), //MPEGv1,     Layers 1,2,3
            2 => array( 1 => 384, 2 =>1152, 3 => 576, ), //MPEGv2/2.5, Layers 1,2,3
        );
        //$b0=ord($fourbytes[0]);//will always be 0xff
        $b1=ord($fourbytes[1]);
        $b2=ord($fourbytes[2]);
        $b3=ord($fourbytes[3]);
 
        $version_bits = ($b1 & 0x18) >> 3;
        $version = $versions[$version_bits];
        $simple_version =  ($version=='2.5' ? 2 : $version);
 
        $layer_bits = ($b1 & 0x06) >> 1;
        $layer = $layers[$layer_bits];
 
        $protection_bit = ($b1 & 0x01);
        $bitrate_key = sprintf('V%dL%d', $simple_version , $layer);
        $bitrate_idx = ($b2 & 0xf0) >> 4;
        $bitrate = isset($bitrates[$bitrate_key][$bitrate_idx]) ? $bitrates[$bitrate_key][$bitrate_idx] : 0;
 
        $sample_rate_idx = ($b2 & 0x0c) >> 2;//0xc => b1100
        $sample_rate = isset($sample_rates[$version][$sample_rate_idx]) ? $sample_rates[$version][$sample_rate_idx] : 0;
        $padding_bit = ($b2 & 0x02) >> 1;
        $private_bit = ($b2 & 0x01);
        $channel_mode_bits = ($b3 & 0xc0) >> 6;
        $mode_extension_bits = ($b3 & 0x30) >> 4;
        $copyright_bit = ($b3 & 0x08) >> 3;
        $original_bit = ($b3 & 0x04) >> 2;
        $emphasis = ($b3 & 0x03);
 
        $info = array();
        $info['Version'] = $version;//MPEGVersion
        $info['Layer'] = $layer;
        //$info['Protection Bit'] = $protection_bit; //0=> protected by 2 byte CRC, 1=>not protected
        $info['Bitrate'] = $bitrate;
        $info['Sampling Rate'] = $sample_rate;
        //$info['Padding Bit'] = $padding_bit;
        //$info['Private Bit'] = $private_bit;
        //$info['Channel Mode'] = $channel_mode_bits;
        //$info['Mode Extension'] = $mode_extension_bits;
        //$info['Copyright'] = $copyright_bit;
        //$info['Original'] = $original_bit;
        //$info['Emphasis'] = $emphasis;
        $info['Framesize'] = self::framesize($layer, $bitrate, $sample_rate, $padding_bit);
        $info['Samples'] = $samples[$simple_version][$layer];
        return $info;
    }
 
    private static function framesize($layer, $bitrate,$sample_rate,$padding_bit)
    {
        if ($layer==1)
            return intval(((12 * $bitrate*1000 /$sample_rate) + $padding_bit) * 4);
        else //layer 2, 3
            return intval(((144 * $bitrate*1000)/$sample_rate) + $padding_bit);
    }
}
```

[Fuente original](http://www.zedwood.com/article/php-calculate-duration-of-mp3)

3. En el mismo directorio, crea el archivo `index.php`, copia y pega el siguiente código:

```html
<?php
    require('mp3file.class.php');

    // Aqui deberias indicar el archivo MP3 que quieras usar
    $mp3file = new MP3File('audio.mp3');
    $duration1 = $mp3file->getDurationEstimate();
    $duration2 = $mp3file->getDuration();

    echo "Duración: $duration1 segundos"."<br/>";
    echo "Estimado: $duration2 segundos"."<br/>";
    echo "Estimado formateado: ".MP3File::formatTime($duration2)."<br/>";
```

4. Por ultimo en el mismo directorio, copia el archivo `MP3` que quieres usar y renombralo a `audio.mp3`.

**Resumen del directorio y archivos**

```
mp3file/
   audio.mp3
   mp3file.cass.php
   index.php
```

**Resultado:**

Por ultimo, abre un navegador e ingresa la `URL` al archivo `index.php` en dicho directorio, por ejemplo, `http://localhost/mp3file/index.php`. El resultado deberías ser el siguiente:

```
Duración: 1 segundos  
Estimado: 1 segundos  
Estimado formateado: 00:00:01
```